# Perl print function adding unwanted newlines to variables

Tags: perl, printing, newline

I thought this would be simple enough. I have two arrays, and I want to print a sentence with numbers from these arrays into a file. I tried this:

```
chomp $array1[$x];
chomp $array2[$x];
print FILE "Number1: $array1[$x] \& Number2: $array2[$x] Some Words\n";
```

Which gives me:

```
Number1: 0
 & Number2: 87.3
 Some Words
```

(Numbers here are just examples.)

Any idea why this is happening?
I've tried using

```
$array1[$x] =~ s/\n//g;
$array2[$x] =~ s/\n//g;
```

as well, but it hasn't fixed anything.
Also, if I explicitly place these extra newlines in, like so:

```
print FILE "Number1: $array1[$x]\n \& Number2: $array2[$x]\n Some Words\n"
```

I get the same output, so the unwanted newlines aren't being added anymore. Why?

Comment: We need to know how `$array[1]` and `$array[2]` are being populated.  What does your "open" look like (if you're reading from a file).  What operating system was the file created on?  What operating system are you using?

Comment: You don't need to escape the `&` unless you print using single quotes.

Comment: @DavidO File was created on Windows, Script is running on Linux.

The arrays were populated by sorting another array (raw), which was populated by reading a file. Each line was 'chomped' before it was read into 'raw'.

Comment: `dos2unix` will help with the line endings for running it on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the file was created on Windows it likely has `CRLF` (i.e. `\r\n`) line termination, not just `LF`.  `chomp` will by default only remove the `LF`.

This line will remove `LF` with an *optional* preceding `CR`:

```
$array1[$x] =~ s/\r?\n//;
```

Alternatively, change `$/` (the default "input record separator") to contain `\r\n`, at which point `chomp` should correctly strip both.

Comment: `\R` was introduced in Perl 5.10 to remove any line ending, just as a side note.  Does exactly what your regex does.